# Open WinSCP stored session using commandline

Tags: scp, winscp

I want to open WinSCP GUI and have it open a stored session automatically, need it for a Windows shortcut to a stored session.

I was hoping this could be done using a commandline option.

Been looking at the [commandline option documentation](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline) with no success to find the right option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first line in the [command-line syntax](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/commandline#parameters):

```
winscp.exe site|workspace|folder
```

So, simply pass a name of your stored site as the only parameter to WinSCP. If the site is stored in a folder, the folder must be specified too, like `folder/site`.